# Bash Script how to get second attribute and his specific value

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to get a specific output from a command that I make as a variable.

this is the command:

```
hwinfo --disk
```

output:

```
11: None 00.0: 10600 Disk                                       
  [Created at block.245]
  Unique ID: +b7l.Fxp0d3BezAE
  Parent ID: JaHa.j9MZgu1IFZ6
  SysFS ID: /class/block/xvda
  SysFS BusID: vbd-768
  SysFS Device Link: /devices/vbd-768
  Hardware Class: disk
  Model: "Disk"
  Driver: "vbd"
  Driver Modules: "xen_blkfront"
  Device File: /dev/xvda
  Device Number: block 202:0-202:15
  Drive status: no medium
  Config Status: cfg=new, avail=yes, need=no, active=unknown
  Attached to: #8 (Storage controller)

12: None 00.0: 10600 Disk
  [Created at block.245]
  Unique ID: SnNp.Fxp0d3BezAE
  Parent ID: h6mc.j9MZgu1IFZ6
  SysFS ID: /class/block/xvdb
  SysFS BusID: vbd-51728
  SysFS Device Link: /devices/vbd-51728
  Hardware Class: disk
  Model: "Disk"
  Driver: "vbd"
  Driver Modules: "xen_blkfront"
  Device File: /dev/xvdb
  Device Files: /dev/xvdb, /dev/disk/by-uuid/e6fc7a51-7f12-4b35-a48e-6cd2db77bcee
  Device Number: block 202:16-202:31
  Drive status: no medium
  Config Status: cfg=new, avail=yes, need=no, active=unknown
  Attached to: #10 (Storage controller)
```

I want to save the second attribute as a variable (12) but only the value of "Device File" which is in this example "/dev/xvdb"

can anyone please help me here?

Comment: what do you mean ?

Comment: i have no code yet

Comment: Sorry but that's not the way Stackoverflow works. It is not a give-me-code   forum?

Comment: i am not asking for a code... i am trying to understand how i can get output from a command , i am pretty new with bash and i thought you can help me a little

Comment: I suggest piping the output of `hwinfo` to an `awk` script that gets the values you want.

Comment: Agree that `awk` is pretty good tool for processing structured text like this using field separator as `: `

Comment: To do this, you could use `grep` with the `-A` flag together with `awk`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats the way i succeeded to store the specific value into a variable from my previous output.

```
hw=$(hwinfo --disk | grep 'Device File:' | cut -d ' ' -f5)
disk=$(echo $hw | cut -d ' ' -f2)

echo $disk 

/dev/xvdb
```

Thank you all.